# How to populate data automatically in excel

Tags: excel

I have three excel sheets one with store codes, one with item codes. I want the third sheet to populate data such that there are two columns one column containing store codes another with item codes and there has to be each item associated with each store. I would also need the sheet to update itself as and when I add or remove data from, the store list. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: There are 2 ways. 1) Simple Excel formula 2) vba with `worksheet_change` event. Btw, What have you tried so far?  updating the question with sample data would help others to help you